# Aggregate certain values in array of dictionary based on key/value criteria

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I have the below JSON of forum posts.
What would be the pythonic way of creating a resulting JSON of aggregated Positive/Negative ratings per forum?

Input Json:

```
{"Posting_Stats":{
      "Posts":[
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:41:00",
            "Forum":"panorama",
            "Positive":2,
            "Negative":0
         },
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:37:00",
            "Forum":"web",
            "Positive":6,
            "Negative":0
         },
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:37:00",
            "Forum":"web",
            "Positive":2,
            "Negative":2
         },...]}
```

Output should be:

```
{"Forum_Stats" : [{"Forum" : "panorama",
                  "Positive":2,
                  "Negative":0},
                 {"Forum" : "web",
                  "Positive":8,
                  "Negative":2},...]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot think of a different way:

```
posts = inputData['Posting_Stats']['Posts']
postAggregator = {}
for post in posts:
    try:
        postAggregator[post['Forum']]['Positive'] += post.get('Positive',0)
        postAggregator[post['Forum']]['Negative'] += post.get('Negative',0)
    except KeyError:
        postAggregator.update({post['Forum']:{"Positive":post.get('Positive',0), "Negative":post.get('Negative',0)}})

outputData = {"Forum_Stats": []}
for key, value in postAggregator.items():
    outputData['Forum_Stats'].append({"Forum":key , "Positive":value['Positive'],"Negative":value['Negative']})

print(outputData)
```

Output:

```
{'Forum_Stats': [{'Forum': 'panorama', 'Positive': 2, 'Negative': 0}, {'Forum': 'web', 'Positive': 8, 'Negative': 2}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be one way of solving:

```
#taking the input in a dictionary
d = {"Posting_Stats":{
      "Posts":[
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:41:00",
            "Forum":"panorama",
            "Positive":2,
            "Negative":0
         },
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:37:00",
            "Forum":"web",
            "Positive":6,
            "Negative":0
         },
         {
            "Date":"2020-03-29 12:37:00",
            "Forum":"web",
            "Positive":2,
            "Negative":2
         }]}}

#iterating over the values to get their some on the basis of forum as key
temp = {}
for i in d.get('Posting_Stats').get('Posts'):
    if temp.get(i.get('Forum')) == None:
        temp[i.get('Forum')] = {}
        temp[i.get('Forum')]['Positive'] = 0
        temp[i.get('Forum')]['Negative'] = 0
    temp[i.get('Forum')]['Positive']+=i.get('Positive')
    temp[i.get('Forum')]['Negative']+=i.get('Negative')
```

## Finally converting the output into the required format

```
output = [{'Forum': i , **temp[i] } for i in temp]
print(output)

#[{'Forum': 'panorama', 'Positive': 2, 'Negative': 0},
#{'Forum': 'web', 'Positive': 8, 'Negative': 2}]
```